# Lift row count and timeout limitations while pulling data from AppInsights

Tags: azure-application-insights

We want to pull data from Application Insights using the REST APIs (see https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/overview). Specifically, we need to retrieve data with "**GET /query**". According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-reference, there is an **implicit limit on the number of rows that can be returned to the client; and there is also a timeout limit.**

When we pull data directly from a Kusto cluster/table, we set '**OptionNoRequestTimeout**' and '**OptionNoTruncation**' properties to **TRUE** in the **Kusto ClientRequestProperties**, which is provided in the Kusto client interface.

I am wondering h**ow I can achieve the same when pulling data with AppInsights "GET /query" REST API to lift the limitation on timeout and number of rows to return?**

The AppInsight Analytics Reference briefly mentions that "To lift the row count limit, use the notruncation client request option." w/o explaining how. **How shall I set these Kusto request properties on the HTTP request URL, which is sent to the target AppInsights application with a HttpClient?**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot currently override the values for row count (500,000) or total size (64,000,000 bytes) through the REST API.

you can, however, override the timeout, by adding a special header:

```
Prefer: wait=[seconds]
```

like

```
Prefer: wait=600
```

for 10 minutes, which is the max.

The `notruncation` part of your question is something you use with `set` in your actual query, like

```
set notruncation;
MyTable | take 500000
```

Comment: Tried to add this header using the API's C# SDK (and using postman, fired requests to the demo app), but to no avail. Do you maybe have any insights?

https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Using-the-API/Timeouts